# Ctrl-C with two simultaneous commands in bash

Tags: shell, signals, background-process, process-management

I want to run two commands simultaneously in bash on a Linux machine. Therefore in my `./execute.sh` bash script I put:

```
command 1 & command 2
echo "done"
```

However when I want to stop the bash script and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, only the second command is stopped. The first command keeps running. 
How do I make sure that the complete bash script is stopped? Or in any case, how do I stop both commands? Because in this case no matter how often I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the command keeps running and I am forced to close the terminal.

Comment: Make the follow up question into a separate question and remove here. Now it is unclear for a visitor if both question was answered, or just the intial question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you type

```
command 1 & command 2
```

this is equal to

```
command 1 &
command 2
```

i.e. this will run the first command in background and then runs the second command in foreground. Especially this means, that your `echo "done"` is printed after `command 2` finished even if `command 1` is still running.

You probably want

```
command 1 &
command 2 &
wait
echo "done"
```

This will run both commands in background and wait for both to complete.

---

If you press CTRL-C this will only send the SIGINT signal to the foreground process, i.e. `command 2` in your version or `wait` in my version.

I would  suggest setting a trap like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap killgroup SIGINT

killgroup(){
  echo killing...
  kill 0
}

loop(){
  echo $1
  sleep $1
  loop $1
}

loop 1 &
loop 2 &
wait
```

With the trap the SIGINT signal produced by CTRL-C is trapped and replaced by the `killgroup` function, which kills all those processes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do however have a follow-up question. I now have the following script:

    trap killgroup SIGINT

    killgroup(){
    echo killing...
    kill 0
   }

   command001

   command1 & command2

I have ommitted the wait command because the script is allowed to continue when command2 is finished.
However it seems that command 1 already starts when I run the script. Can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: command1 starts directly after command001 is finished. you can use `set -x` at the beginning of your script to print the commands that are executed.

Answer (score 7):

When putting a command into the background from a script, the PID is not displayed on the screen. You can use the builtin variable `$!` which stores the PID of the last process so you can capture the PID of command1.

```
command1 &
echo $!
```

would echo the PID of command1.

Bash also provides the trap builtin which you can use to register a sequence of commands to run when particular signals are received. You can use this to catch the SIGINT and kill command1 before exiting the main script e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

onINT() {
echo "Killing command1 $command1PID too"
kill -INT "$command1PID"
exit
}

trap "onINT" SIGINT
command1 &
command1PID="$!"
comamnd2
echo Done
```

Now, whilst command 2 is running, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> will cause both command1 and command2 to be sent SIGINT.

Comment: You can also use `%n` syntax to kill specific background jobs in this shell. Usually you issue `kill %1` to kill the latest and the only background process. With more background processes, use `jobs` to see the list first.

Comment: @9000: Yes but the OP is running their commands in a script (./execute.sh) so getting jobs to work is much more problematic surely ?

Comment: @lain: certainly. I missed the point about the running from a script.

Answer (score 5):

Newer versions of GNU Parallel will do what you want:

```
parallel ::: "command 1" "command 2"
echo "done"
```

Or if `command` remains the same:

```
parallel command ::: 1 2
echo done
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
with love you for it.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT signal to your front process, which is `command2`. `command1` is run in background, therefore not concerned by the input stream.

When you type `command1 &`, bash should give you the process' PID, something like `[1234]`. To kill this process, you can use `kill 1234`. Now, if you have the PIDs of both `command1` and `command2` (have a look at `ps -ef`), you can use `kill` to terminate them all :

```
kill pid1 pid2 pid3 ...
```

A little trick would be to run both commands in background, with :

```
command1 & command2 &
```

Bash will give you both PIDs, ready to get killed. Another trick would be to bring back `command1` in the foreground once you killed `command2` :

```
command1 & command2
# Hit Ctrl+C : command2 terminates.

fg # Bring back command1 to foreground.
# Hit Ctrl+C again, command1 terminates.
```

More info available here : http://linuxg.net/how-to-manage-background-and-foreground-processes/